# SVN revert unchanged files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, svn

I use both SVN and Git for a project.

I tried some changes with git and also did a checkout to a very old version. The result is that after returning to Git HEAD, SVN thinks that all files have changed.

How can I tell SVN to take out all unchanged files in the 'pending changes' list?